# Lodash groupby, step value, sum and sort together for order book grouping on array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, grouping, lodash

I have an array of objects as follows

```
var orders={
  '8549.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 380210 },
  '8549.0': { side: 'Sell', size: 51700 },
  '8548.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 14136 },
  '8547.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 1108 },
  '8547': { side: 'Sell', size: 84190 },
  '8544.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 65800 },
  '8543.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 24755 },
  '8542.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 6233 },
  '8541.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 10206 },
  '8540.5': { side: 'Sell', size: 228742 },
  '8539.5': { side: 'Buy', size: 4001 },
  '8538.5': { side: 'Buy', size: 50001 },
  '8537.5': { side: 'Buy', size: 75000 },
  '8536.5': { side: 'Buy', size: 77367 },
  '8535.5': { side: 'Buy', size: 75000 }}
```

I want to achieve the following:

- If the grouping index is 1 - all order prices need to be grouped by 1 so (8549, 8548, 8547 and so on.)
- The sizes need to be summed together
- Total of all sizes per side

I have tried a regular looping method but it's really slow and the size of the object is around 50000 to 250000 keys.

The end result that I'm getting currently with grouping 1 is:

```
Sell: [{"price": 8549, "size": 431910, "total": 431910}, 
        {"price": 8548, "size": 14136, "total": 446046}, 
        {"price": 8547, "size": 85298, "total": 531344 } 
        ...

and similar for sell
```

is there a lodash implementation that can solve the grouping index, sum and total?

This is the current min code

```
var realTimelastPrice=null;
var lastPriceSide=null;
var bid=null; var ask=null;
var order={};
var orderBook={};
var orderSell={};
var orderBuy={};



function setBids(gapPrice)
{

   var lastPrice = this.realTimelastPrice

   var startBuyPrice = this.bid

   gapPrice=parseFloat(gapPrice)

   var showMaximum = 10

   var startBuyViewPrice = Math.floor(startBuyPrice/gapPrice)*gapPrice


   var tmpOrder = {
      price:null,
      size:null,
      total: null

   }
   var currentBuyViewPrice = startBuyViewPrice
   var totalBuy=0;
    var buys;
   var cntShow = 0


   for(var price = startBuyPrice;cntShow<=showMaximum;price -= 0.5)
   {

      if(this.orderBook[price]==undefined)
         continue
      var tmpSize = this.orderBook[price].size;

      if(currentBuyViewPrice>price)
      {
         currentBuyViewPrice -= gapPrice

         tmpOrder['size'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['size'])
         tmpOrder['total'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(totalBuy)
         tmpOrder['price'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['price'].toFixed(1))

         buys+='<tr><td style="color:white !important;">'+tmpOrder['total']+'</td><td style="color:white !important;">'+commaNumber(tmpOrder['size'])+'</td><td>'+tmpOrder['price']+'</td></tr>'

         tmpOrder = {
            price:null,
            size:null,
            total: null
         }
         cntShow += 1
      }
      totalBuy+=tmpSize;
      if(tmpOrder['price']==null)
      {
         tmpOrder['price'] = currentBuyViewPrice
         tmpOrder['size'] = tmpSize
      }
      else
      {
         tmpOrder['size'] += tmpSize    
      }
      if(showMaximum==cntShow) break

   }

         $(".orderbook-table-bids tbody").html(buys)

}


 function setAsks(gapPrice)
{
   var startSellPrice = this.ask
   gapPrice=parseFloat(gapPrice)
   var showMaximum = 12

   var startSellViewPrice = Math.ceil(startSellPrice/gapPrice)*gapPrice

   var tmpOrder = {
      price:null,
      size:null,
      total:null
   }

   var totalSell=0;
   var currentSellViewPrice = startSellViewPrice
   var sells;
   var cntShow = 0

   for(var price = startSellPrice;cntShow<=showMaximum;price += 0.5)
   {
      var tmpViewPrice = currentSellViewPrice
      if(this.orderBook[price]==undefined)
         continue
      var tmpSize = this.orderBook[price].size;

      if(currentSellViewPrice<price)
      {
         currentSellViewPrice += gapPrice

         tmpOrder['total'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(totalSell)
        tmpOrder['size'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['size'])
         tmpOrder['price'] = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(tmpOrder['price'].toFixed(1))


            sells+='<tr><td >'+tmpOrder['price']+'</td><td style="color:white !important;">'+commaNumber(tmpOrder['size'])+'</td><td style="color:white !important;">'+tmpOrder['total']+'<td></tr>'

         tmpOrder = {
            price:null,
            size:null,
            total: null
         }
         cntShow += 1
      }
      totalSell += tmpSize
      if(tmpOrder['price']==null)
      {
         tmpOrder['price'] = currentSellViewPrice
         tmpOrder['size'] = tmpSize
      }
      else
      {
         tmpOrder['size'] += tmpSize    
      }


      if(showMaximum==cntShow) break

   }
         $(".orderbook-table-asks tbody").html(sells)
}

async function appendOrderbooks(res)
{
   var data = res.data
   var action = res.action

   if(action==='partial')
   {
      data.forEach(async ($element) => {

         if($element.side == 'Sell' && realTimelastPrice <= $element.price && ask > $element.price)
            {
                ask = $element.price
            }

            if($element.side == 'Buy' && realTimelastPrice >= $element.price && bid < $element.price)
            {
                bid = $element.price
         }

         order[$element.id] = $element
         orderBook[$element.price] = {
            side:$element.side,
            size:$element.size
         }

      })
   }


   if(action==='insert')
   {
      data.forEach(async ($element) => {
         if($element.side == 'Sell' && realTimelastPrice <= $element.price && ask > $element.price)
            {
                ask = $element.price
            }

            if($element.side == 'Buy' && realTimelastPrice >= $element.price && bid < $element.price)
            {
               bid = $element.price
            }
         order[$element.id] = $element
         orderBook[$element.price] = {
            side:$element.side,
            size:$element.size
         }

      })
   }
   if(action==='update')
   {
      data.forEach(async ($element) => {
         if($element.side == 'Sell' && realTimelastPrice <= $element.price && ask > $element.price)
            {
                ask = $element.price
            }

            if($element.side == 'Buy' && realTimelastPrice >= $element.price && bid < $element.price)
            {
                bid = $element.price
            }

         var tmpPrice = order[$element.id].price
            orderBook[tmpPrice] = {side:$element.side,size: $element.size}

      })

   }
   if(action==='delete')
   {
      data.forEach(async ($element) => {

         delete order[$element.id]
      })
   }
   var gapPrice =  1
   var debounceCalculate = _.debounce(setBids, 0, false);
   debounceCalculate(gapPrice);
    debounceCalculate = _.debounce(setAsks, 0, false);
   debounceCalculate(gapPrice);
}


var ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?");

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
if(e.table=="orderBookL2")
{
appendOrderbooks(e)
}
if(e.table=="instrument")
{

    if('lastPrice' in e.data[0])
    realTimelastPrice=data[0].lastPrice

    if('bidPrice' in e.data[0])
{
   bid=data[0].bidPrice;
}
if('askPrice' in e.data[0])
{
ask=data[0].askPrice;
}

}
}
```

Essentially the grouping feature available on bitmex orderbook.

Comment: what does not work with your code?

Comment: *My code is slow* ... what code?  You haven't shown anything for anyone to troubleshoot. Suggest you take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have updated the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries from the data, group by the integer value of the keys and create an object of objects with the wanted sides.

The second part uses the temporary object, gets the keys, sort them descending and maps new entries with the wanted totals. Finally create a new object.

```js
var orders = { 8549.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 380210 }, 8549.0: { side: 'Sell', size: 51700 }, 8548.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 14136 }, 8547.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 1108 }, 8547: { side: 'Sell', size: 84190 }, 8544.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 65800 }, 8543.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 24755 }, 8542.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 6233 }, 8541.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 10206 }, 8540.5: { side: 'Sell', size: 228742 }, 8539.5: { side: 'Buy', size: 4001 }, 8538.5: { side: 'Buy', size: 50001 }, 8537.5: { side: 'Buy', size: 75000 }, 8536.5: { side: 'Buy', size: 77367 }, 8535.5: { side: 'Buy', size: 75000 } },
    temp = Object
        .entries(orders)
        .reduce((r, [k, { side, size }]) => {
            const price = Math.floor(k);
            r[side][price] = r[side][price] || { price, size: 0 };
            r[side][price].size += size;
            return r;
        }, { Sell: {}, Buy: {} }),
    result = Object.fromEntries(
        Object
            .entries(temp)
            .map(([k, o]) => [
                k,
                Object
                    .keys(o)
                    .sort((a, b) => b - a)
                    .map((total => k => ({ ...o[k], total: total += o[k].size }))(0))
            ])
    );


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How do I limit the results to say 10 or 20 and also change the grouping index to 5, 10 or 15?
I'm creating the   grouping of orderbook as here: https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD

Comment: you could take a wanted range and change price to `const price = Math.floor(k / range) * range;`

Comment: with 30000 keys in orders, this solution becomes very slow. Is there way to limit the map to do only 20 results?

Comment: if i would know, what you mean with 20 results?

Comment: after sorting, I need only 20 Buys and 20 Sells results to display.. because it tries to sort and map 30000 keys, it becomes slow.

Comment: i have still no idea. please add an example of 20 keyed object and let give four of them as result.